# messed up perfectly good install of win10 with vbox would reinstalling vbox 1 possibly correct the problems

Tags: virtualbox, windows

I messed up a perfectly good install of win10 using vbox and ubuntu 18.04 as host.

Ubuntu 18.04 is the booting OS which hosts VirtualBox (ver. 6.1 w/ guest additions).

Windows 10 is a guest under VirtualBox.

I inadvertently installed VirtualBox within the virtualized Windows 10.

Would reinstalling vbox clear things up or should I reinstall windows 1st.  The problems or with the screen size when I run windows and the internet connection.  I have both running but in differnt configs then before and this is causing problems.  Just can't figure out how to fix windows and what to reinstall first?  Please help.  I'm an Ubuntu newbie.

Comment: Do you have a dual boot installation of Ubuntu and Windows 10? If so, which Ubuntu version? Which Virtual Box version? Is Virtual Box installed into Ubuntu, Windows, or both?

Comment: @K7AAY  I have single boot of 18.04.  I have win10 installed on virtual-box 6.1 with guest editions. The host is Ubuntu.  I mistakenly installed virtual-box with guest additions on windows and this messed up both the windows network and the size of windows on my monitors.  everything was fine until I made that install mistake. This is a home network.  Do I make any sense?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the problem by first Uninstalling vbox 6.1 on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. Then I reinstalled vbox 6.1 to newest revision.  After that i updated Ubuntu. Then I uninstalled Win 10 using the fresh install option in windows. I deleted all my files and directories of win10 during the process. This will also delete windows office as well so make sure you have your win office activation key. After that I rebooted Ubuntu and reinstalled win10 and office 2019. Then updated ububuntu again.  After this all problems were solved and it even solved the issue of win10 not recognizing any of my usb's when I tried to use them, so it works better than before, all problems solved. (don't worry about your virtual OS's they will not be deleted when u uninstall vbox.)